# How to query data based based on different query parameter spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm new to spring boot framework and i was developing spring boot rest API.

i have endpoint and i have query the database from spring boot

```
/buy?projectionId=value1&place=value2  // we can add different query parameters here
```

how to write a controller and service using spring boot.

Comment: giving little snippet is fine

Comment: `We can add different query parameters here!` Are you referring to there will be more than 2 query parameters ?

Comment: Yes..sometimes single parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass multiple params in url like, for example:

```
http://localhost:2000/custom?brand=dell&limit=20&price=20000&sort=asc
```

and in order to get this query fields , you can use map like

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/custom")
public String controllerMethod(@RequestParam Map<String, String> customQuery) {

    System.out.println("customQuery = brand " + customQuery.get("brand"));
    System.out.println("customQuery = limit " + customQuery.get("limit"));
    System.out.println("customQuery = price " + customQuery.get("price"));
    System.out.println("customQuery = other " + customQuery.get("other"));
    System.out.println("customQuery = sort " + customQuery.get("sort"));

    return customQuery.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. **You can use like below and add more request param.**

   ```
   @GetMapping("/buy")
   public String buy(@RequestParam("projectionId") long projectionId, 
            @RequestParam("place") String place){
      return "some response"; 
   }
   ```

API ENDPOINT: http://your hostname:port/buy?projectionId=value1&place=value2

```
If you have multiple parameter you can prepare one json.

{
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value2", 
  "field3": "value", 
  "field4": "value",
  "field5": "value5",
  "field6": "value6" 
}

**This JSON take as a payload.**

 public String buy(@RequestBody String payload){  
if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(payload)){
     //String convert into class.
     Test test = new ObjectMapper().readValue(payload, Test.class);
     //Then whatever you want you can use it.

   } 
 return "some response";
```

}

API ENDPOINT: http://your hostname:port/buy

Request body:  {
"field1": "value1",
"field2": "value2",
"field3": "value",
"field4": "value",
"field5": "value5",
"field6": "value6"
}

Answer (score 0):

```
@GetMapping("/api/buy")
@ResponseBody
public String getBuy(@RequestParam String protectId) {
    return "ID: " + protectId;

}

example request will be
http://localhost:8080/api/buy?protectId=abc
```

Comment: Thanks for response. but it works for single parameter but it could be many parameters right. how to do that

Comment: For that you can make a list in your arguments like;

Comment: @GetMapping("/api/buy")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getBuy(@RequestParam List<String> id) {
        return "IDs are " + id;
    }

Comment: Sample request will be http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-basics/api/foos?id=1&id=2, // ID = [1,2]

Comment: Please [edit] your answer instead of adding comments, so that code can be formatted and everything is in one place. Also, it would help if you added an explanation, vs just a code dump.